# Gazebo model for OMRON OS32C

Tags: ros-industrial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a gazebo model available along with the [Omron-ros driver](https://github.com/ros-drivers/omron)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286241/gazebo-model-for-omron-os32c/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:
You tagged this with `ros-industrial`, but at least in the ROS-Industrial project/repositories, I do not know of any model for that particular scanner. Note also that the driver is not hosted by any of the ROS-Industrial organisations.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-22**:
That was just a hopeful attempt in case anyone had used the sensor with `ros-industrial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since there are no gazebo models for the Omron OS32C laser scanner, I have designed a primitive version using the CAD models and data from [Omron website](http://www.omron.com.au/products/family/2717/download/cad.html). The gazebo model can be found [here](https://github.com/prajval10/Omron_model).

---

Originally posted by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) with karma: 92 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2